# trace the data flow when the executable is running

Tags: reverse-engineering, reverse

I am practicing reversing skill using OLLdbg under windows.

there is an interactive window asking you input, let's say "serial number". My question is when user operate on the window, it is hard to locate related data flow within the debugger window. For example, if I click "F9", we can view the instruction flow; but When inputing on the window, I can't know which instructions have been executed.

My target is to find some jump instruction and change it, so that I can bypass the correct input requirement. I think the instruction should be quite close to instruction related to arg#, and related to TEST command.

Looking for hint or trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is type something in the text field and then use an application such as Cheat Engine to find out where in the memory these characters are stored. Then you can put a memory (on access) breakpoint on the address of the first character in ollydbg. Then press the button that verifies the serial. When an instructions accesses this part of the memory it will break. You're inside a part of the code that verifies your string. Now from here you have to try to understand what the code is doing to find the instruction you want to alter.

Depending on how secure the application is, this will work. With a more secure application this most likely won't work. When your just starting reverse engineering I suggest you find some easy applications made for cracking and work your way to the more secure applications. A site where you can find many of these "crackmes" is [crackmes.de](http://www.crackmes.de). Also i can suggest lene151's tutorials [here](http://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.2876). Some of the best tutorials I've seen on reverse engineering.

Comment: The link is very helpful. Setting a BP on "GetWindowTextA", I am being able to land in the registration scheme code. But, Looks like the scheme is a little complicated which involves about three hundred instructions. I can read some valuable information such as my input serial number is Arg2 and there is "guessed Arg1". Also, I feel instructions: CMP DWORD PTR SS:[], DCBAABCD; JNE 7707003B0 (jump is not taken) are points that I might work on. Needs more time to clarify the whole scheme and figure out one solution of it.